# append tr in table jquery not working correct

Tags: jquery, html-table, append, dynamic-values

I want to add new row in table with dynamic values when user click in `li` element. But when user click it suddenly add 2 rows in table not 1. Why?

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('.wpforms-field-payment-multiple ul li').click(function(){
    var price = $(this).find('input').data('amount');
    var parent = $(this).closest('.wpforms-field-payment-multiple');
    var titles = $('.wpforms-field-description',parent).html();
    $('#booking .right .price table tbody').append('<tr><td class="name">'+titles+'</td><td class="pr">'+price+'</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: This shouldn't add 2 rows. Maybe you added the click handler twice? Is this code inside another event handler?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I checked. But just 1 event handler on li tag

Comment: Add console.log statements to see if the function is being called multiple times.

Comment: this my log:
(index):1355 s.fn.init [li.choice-1.wpforms-image-choices-item, prevObject: s.fn.init(1)]
(index):1355 s.fn.init [li.choice-1.wpforms-image-choices-item, prevObject: s.fn.init(1)]

you can see two li element with same class and same line i n index

Comment: What are you logging? I meant something like `console.log("Adding row")`

Comment: But it does look like it's being run multiple times. Is this event handler call inside another event handler? Every time the outer event happens, you'll add another inner handler.

Comment: I'll ask again: Please post an executable example.

Comment: if you can check this url: https://fixtman.com/demo-new-form/

and click on (book a service) in left-middle widow .
after that click on (Tv Wall mounting) ->  and then click one of the (tv size) . that you can see at the right of popup box that rows insert.

Comment: this jquery code in response function ajax . is it wrong???

Comment: I was right, this event handler is inside `$('#choose .ccontent .service').click(function()`. So every time you click on `.service`, the AJAX callback function adds another click handler to all the `.wpforms-field-payment-multiple ul li` elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements for the correct way to bind event handlers to dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

JS looks ok to me but check your HTML. You probably have a nested UL,LI tags.

Example below.

```js
$('.wpforms-field-payment-multiple ul li').click(function() {
  alert("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wpforms-field-payment-multiple">
  <ul>
    <li>
      One Alert
      <ul>
        <li>
          Two Alerts
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I know what did you say. But when i checked inside li element isn't any ul tag. In fact inside li is label tag and inside label tag is input radio button that i use radio's value.